# How do you specify the filename for errors with eval() in PHP?

Tags: php

When calling eval in Ruby you can specify a filename to display in errors to make it easier to see which block of code passed to eval caused a problem. In PHP eval only seems to take one argument. Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` does not support such a parameter you know from ruby.

However, you can install a PHP extension called [`xdebug`](http://xdebug.org/) which [displays a *stacktrace*](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace) in case of an error/warning - so for the `eval` part as well.

In any case you should take care when dealing with eval and think about what you can do to not make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could do a [backtrace](http://cr.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to find out where it came from